# Increment Value on Model using Ajax and Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looping through a collection on my model using Razor to display it. As an example:

```
@foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    <span id='item-@item.Id'>@item.Quantity</span>
    <button type='button' onclick='updateQuantity(@item.Quantity+1);'>Add One</button>
}
```

In this example, `updateQuantity` performs an AJAX request, gets the new quantity back, and updates `item-@item.Id` with the new quantity. However, because `@item.Quantity` is pulled from the model (passed in via the page's `GET` method, `@item.Quantity` is never updated with the new value until the page is reloaded.

My question is: How can I make sure I'm always using the latest value, without having to reload the page?

Comment: You want to get latest item without refreshing the page?

Comment: I think the best way for doing that is using SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button inside your foreach loop like this:

```
@foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    <span id='item-@item.Id'>@item.Quantity</span>
    <button id='updateButton' type='button'>Add One</button>
}
```

And, add this script to your View:

```
<script>
    $("#updateButton").click(function() {
       var quantity = $("#item-@item.Id").text();
       updateQuantity(quantity);
    })
</script>
```

And, in your `updateQuantity()` function, update the text inside the span after getting it back through Ajax.

Comment: I'm going to try this!